# How to find a link without id- or class-attribute in a page made out of frames in a seleniumtest?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is my first post, I hope do not do anything wrong.

Well, I am currently trying to implement some selenium-tests for a webapplication made out of frames.

The major problem is to get the logic behind it so dynamic that a person without any experience in programming could write test-scenarios. I've defined a step to navigate in the site and now I need to get the link that needs to be clicked just by the text that is displayed in the link, because 99% of the links on the site do not have an id or class or anything.

There are frames and frames in those frames and even frames in these frames! Frame-ception. The link can be in ANY of those frames.

I had the idea to search recursively in all of those frames (as far as I know the selenium-webdriver can only "look" at elements in the frame he is currently in?) for the element or, if not found, other frames to continue searching and displaying an exception or something if it can't be found in any of those frames.

I have a really big problem to search recursively. Whenever a frame has frames in it, I am calling the methode again, giving the current frame as a parameter so the webdriver can switch back to the parent-frame, but whenever the WebDriver should jump back I get an Exception telling me that the frame can't be found.

As it seems, the WebDriver can only get into frames, but not back out there, except with the **webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent()**-methode, which brings him back to the absolute top.

Is there any way to do something like this? My next idea would be to have an Array or List or something where I store my "visited" frames and I am getting in there from the top all the time, trying to find a new, unvisited frame, but that would be really uncool...

Also, hardcoding all the frames is not an option because there are frames that are dynamically produced and not known to anyone until they exist.

Thanks in advance, I am not that pro and still have to learn vey much, if this is a silly question I apologize!

Comment: To locate the link by the text displayed, you can try to use this command, [driver.find_element_by_link_text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text). I think you can create a multi-dimensional array to store all frames you found when you are doing recursive search for frames.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is way too broad for this forum. Please have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I do not unterstand which of the rules I broke with my question? I actually just want to know how to jump back in a parent-frame or if this is really not possible if someone with more experience has an idea about how to solve this.

Comment: Your original post could have been just the last statement from the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

To switch back to parent frame, you can use:

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

> Change focus to the parent context. If the current context is the top level browsing context, the context remains unchanged.